# Cloning git repo

Tags: android, git

Today I cloned a Git repo successfully (I hope), however I can not see any source files in the cloned directory. To be specific I cloned the `msm-kernel` repo from Google with the command:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git kernel_msm
```

Comment: what does `du -shc kernel_msm` give you? what about `ls -la kernel_msm`?

Comment: yeah .git folder is there.. and the size is 369MiB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The master branch of this repo is empty. You need to check out the proper branch:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/android-msm-2.6.35
  remotes/origin/master
$ git checkout android-msm-2.6.35
Checking out files: 100% (33866/33866), done.
Branch android-msm-2.6.35 set up to track remote branch android-msm-2.6.35 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'android-msm-2.6.35'
$ ls
COPYING     MAINTAINERS arch        firmware    ipc     net     sound
CREDITS     Makefile    block       fs      kernel      samples     tools
Documentation   README      crypto      include     lib     scripts     usr
Kbuild      REPORTING-BUGS  drivers     init        mm      security    virt
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And the kernel was supposed to be 3.0 for ICS I think.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, master has no files. You have to checkout a branch:

```
git checkout --track -b android-msm-2.6.35 origin/android-msm-2.6.35
```