# the git clone is empty? why this happens

Tags: git, git-clone

This always perplexes me. 
I was cloning this

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git
```

And It seemed to be cloning resolving and receiving objects etc for long .
Then when it is done...

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git
Cloning into msm...
remote: Counting objects: 1636832, done
remote: Total 1636832 (delta 1367313), reused 1636832 (delta 1367313)
Receiving objects: 100% (1636832/1636832), 324.89 MiB | 331 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1367314/1367314), done.
```

I open the `msm` directory to find it empty.
This has happened before.
Any one has an explanation as to what went wrong?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557209/cloning-git-repo

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This particular git repository seems to not have any contents on its `master` branch, which is the branch git checks out by default. It does however have another branch:

```
% git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/android-msm-2.6.35
  remotes/origin/master
```

So if you check out this branch:

```
% git checkout android-msm-2.6.35
Checking out files: 100% (33866/33866), done.
Branch android-msm-2.6.35 set up to track remote branch android-msm-2.6.35 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'android-msm-2.6.35'
```

then there's also content in the working tree.

Answer (score 11):

After your first clone, if you have directories that are submodules of the parent repo, you need to initialize them with:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Using `git submodule update --init --recursive` will also be needed if there are submodules inside submodules.

Comment: Are the submodules their own git repo?

Comment: @birwin, yes git allows you to commit a hash (ie reference) of an entirely different git repo. This can be useful for common libraries. Making the library code a repo and adding it as a submodule to your project makes it a good way to share and maintain across different projects. (At that point it would be like picking up a dependency version that you can directly source control).

Comment: That is a great feature. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that repository was cloned.  Now you have to checkout something.   What  happens if you issue:

```
git branch
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use the following command.

```
> git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

Here -b is just an alias for --branch.
And you can replace "" with the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Also, what happened on my system just now  (windows 7). The automatic initialization (git init) did not take place during the

```
git clone URL
```

Operation. Also got the same succesful clone msg.

After I did a 'manual'

```
git init
```

The clone operation resulted in a dir with contents. After I repeated it.

So, just try a git init if a dir is empty after a git clone (and the master branch is not empty). Then repeat the clone.