# empty directory after clone

Tags: git, clone, git-branch

I searched earlier questions before asking here and found but the proposed solution which worked did not work for me.

After clone operation, I see empty folder although it seems that lots of files have been downloaded.

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:optival.git
Cloning into 'optival'...
remote: Counting objects: 611, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (468/468), done.
remote: Total 611 (delta 157), reused 541 (delta 122)
Receiving objects: 100% (611/611), 9.31 MiB | 560.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (157/157), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

When I open folder 'optival', I see that it is empty. Same question has been asked before:

[the git clone is empty? why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004192/the-git-clone-is-empty-why-this-happens)

I read and changed my branch where code exists but result is same after clone operation

Comment: wich Plaform is used (Windows, Linux,...)?

Comment: It is obvious that both `master` and other branches are empty.

Comment: `I read and changed my branch where code exists but result is same after clone operation` - So, after cloning, did you go into the folder and do a checkout of another branch? Cloning will always pull down the `master` branch. It's up to you to checkout the correct branch.

Comment: You can run `git log` and see if there has been any activity on the branch that you have checked out (the one which you think has code).

Comment: @Oswald I am using Ubuntu.  J. Titus I cloned after changing branch but result is same. Amit when I write "git log", it writes :  fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

Comment: Please make sure that the files are not being ignored, check the contents of `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible and plausible that the repository you're cloning doesn't have any file on the working tree on the branch master at the revision you're checked at, or any visible file at least (check with `ls -a` if there are hidden files).

You can check the `git log` to see the recent modifications, as if someone erased all the file.

Comment: There is not any hidden file except .git and .project

Comment: `.project` sounds like something versionned.

Comment: I tried by using "Egit" Eclipse plugin instead of terminal, it worked. I don't know why it doesn't work from terminal