# Cloned repository is empty except for the .git folder

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I forked and cloned the UnrealEngine repository with the branch selected as Release. The following is the output:

```
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20158/20158), done.
remote: Total 3661983 (delta 20138), reused 20153 (delta 20137), pack-reused 3641825
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2344882/2344882), done.
```

The repository seems to have downloaded completely but there is only a .git folder inside it. I also can on running  `git branch -a` it lists no branch and when i ran `git checkout master` it said - `Switched to a new branch 'master'`. I also can't click on the branch menu in Github Desktop. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the git clone is empty? why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004192/the-git-clone-is-empty-why-this-happens)

Comment: If you give `git clone` a `-b` option that points to a *tag*, you'll get a detached-HEAD checkout in a clone with no branches. That's because all clones (except mirror clones anyway) start out as having no branches: it's the last step of `clone`, when it runs `checkout`, where it creates a branch. But `-b` allows the use of tag names, in which case the checkout step doesn't create any branch. Still, I'd generally expect a project to tag only release commits that *do* have files in them, so something is probably wrong.